# Update Firestore Field, but field is a varaible

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to pass the field to be updated withing firestore as a variable?

I want to create an a function to update a document such as...

`updateFirebaseDocument('enquiries', 'asdaasdasds, 'status', '1'))`

with the following function

```
export async function updateFirebaseDocument(collectionName, documentId, field, updateValue) {
    var doc = db.collection(collectionName).doc(documentId)
    return doc.update({
        field: updateValue
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Which does work, but the issue is, that it creates a field called field, rather then updating the status field. Is there a way of doing this rather then hard-coding the update fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can do without ES6

```
export async function updateFirebaseDocument(collectionName, documentId, field, updateValue) {
    var doc = db.collection(collectionName).doc(documentId)

    var obj = {}
    obj[field] = updateValue;
 
    return doc.update(obj)
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using square brackets solved this for me.

```
      [field]: updateValue
```

Comment: The term is the `object's property or key`, so we are not confused :). Yes, you can use `ComputedPropertyName` as part of the grammar for object literals as you demonstrated. But that only works for ES6.